# Проблема с параллельным программированием двух ESP-12F

Tags: visual-studio-code

Я пишу программу для работы двух ESP где одна выступает AP другая к ней подключается, мне нужно сделать так чтобы я мог при закачке выбирать какую программу установить
Если что пишу на Platformio VS code Можно это сделать создав несколько WorkSpace-ов
, но тогда нужно между ними перепдключать путём файл файл WorkSpace-ов перейти через 15 кликов сам код не важен т.к. я его буду менять

Comment: Ничего не понятно, но очень интересно

Comment: WTFisGoingOn я пытаюсь заставить работать с двумя корневыми папками, содержащими проекты VS code что они не конфликтовали друг с другом(проекты) на то кому компилиться